# products that sold more than in the past year

Tags: sql

I want to see what products sold more in 2021 than in 2020 but i have no idea how to join the tables. I have 4 tables:

- Clients(idclient,name,location)
- Sales(num_sale,idclient,date_sale)
- Items(id_item,num_sale,cod_prod,quantity,price_unit) and
- product(cod_prod,desc,price).

I know I have to do it with quantity but I just don’t know how

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL? They aren't the same, nor do they support the same SQL features and functions. The version matters as well. PostgreSQL has windowing functions that can be used to solve this problem that were only added to MySQL in v 8

Comment: Also make sure you edit your question to make it readable if you want to get answers. People will simply ignore unreadable questions, or downvote them

Comment: @Nathan_Sav don't post code in comments. It's unreadable

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry.  Was more of a thought than an answer. :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

something like so.  Not sure if you could just use the subqueries in a where statement, not tested this yet, an idea though.  Also dont know what you're using, a pivot would be a better solution i think.

```
select q.*
from
(
select distinct
p2.cod_prod,
(
select
sum(i.quantity) as QTY
from
products as p
left join items as i on p.cod_prod=i.cod_prod
left join sales as s on i.num_sale=s.num_sale
where p.cod_prod=p2.cod_prod and year(s.date_sale)=2020
group by p.cod_prod
) as QTY_2020,
(
select
sum(i.quantity) as QTY
from
products as p
left join items as i   on p.cod_prod=i.cod_prod
left join sales as s on i.num_sale=s.num_sale
where p.cod_prod=p2.cod_prod and year(s.date_sale)=2021
group by p.cod_prod
) as QTY_2021
from
products as p2
) as q
where q.qty_2021>q.qty_2020
```